# trying to make a textView change with image in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, textview

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` and in the middle of these i have a `Button` which when pressed will set a different image in the `ImageView`. What I want to achieve is when pressed, I would like the `TextView` to change also so that different text is displayed with each different image. Greatly appreciate some help with this. You will find the code below. Thank you.

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SecondTourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Integer images[] = {R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8, R.drawable.image9,
    R.drawable.image10, R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12, R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14,
            R.drawable.image15, R.drawable.image16, R.drawable.image17, R.drawable.image18,};
    private int currImage = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_tour);


        setInitialImage();
        setImageRotateListener();
    }
    private void setImageRotateListener() {
        final Button rotatebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRotateImage);
        rotatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currImage++;
                if (currImage == 12) {
                    currImage = 0;
                }
                setCurrentImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setInitialImage() {
        setCurrentImage();
    }

    private void setCurrentImage() {

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[currImage]);

    }

}
```

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="jamie2dog.com.listintent.SecondTourActivity"
    android:background="#020202">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This first picture is liverpool lime street station, taken in 2008, continue to next image for more details."
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next image"
        android:id="@+id/btnRotateImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when button click image and text change?

Comment: yes, so different text is displayed to each different image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
          currImage++;
          if (currImage == 12) {
                currImage = 0;
          }
          setCurrentImage();
          final TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
          textView.setText("What ever Text you want to set")
     }
```

Use the above code. The idea is to have a HashMap where for each image, you have a text (or a Model class with Image and Text as the fields). So for each image you can get the text and set the text for the TextView.

Do something like this:

```
    final HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(R.drawable.image5, R.string.text5);
    // add all other things to this map
    // obtain the map here
    int text5 = map.get(R.drawable.image5);
    String text = getResources().getString(text5);
```

Comment: will this set diiferent text description for each image? i will have about 20 different images and want to a discription for each one displayed, so far i have text in the textview in the xml

Comment: As i said you need a Map where for each image there is a corresponding text. How are you planning to do this ?

Comment: i was thinking an array of each text discription under where the array of images are in the above java class, then setting them to the same button for where each image is so that each image will display with the right text description, not 100% sure as a bit confused how this would work

Comment: Updated my answer. Put all your text as resources in the `strings.xml` and map them to the `drawable`.

Comment: will see how i get on with this,should i leave out the textview to set text on your first answer? thank you

Comment: No. You will be replacing "What ever Text you want to set" with the `text` variable.

Comment: hi Henry, i didnt use the hasmap, i just used your first answer and upon testing it works a treat and for each image is displaying the text exactly how i wanted it to do, so thank you so much for your time and help in helping to solve my problem